# How to raise an event between two different forms ( of the same program)

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a MDI form that will open a logon form so the user can be authenticated

when the user hits the logon button and is properly authenticated i wanted to trigger an event that the parent form could pick up and change some variables ((authenticated = true) for example)

I understand how to do this in something like a textbox or a costume usercontrol but im not clear on how to do it between forms because i usually do it through the designer view

can someone walk me through triggering an event on a diffrent form?

Comment: How come you can't just show the logon form modally and wait for it to return the data back to the parent form?

Comment: Use the ShowDialog method to show the form. This blocks the calling code until the logon form is closed. After the logon form is closed, the calling code can then read the data it needs from properties that you add to the logon form. No need for events.

Comment: if showdialog == dialogreslut.ok) how would you use it for a form though?

Answer (score 2):

In the parent form, something like:

```
loginForm.Authenticated += MyEventHandler;
```

or

```
loginForm.Authenticated += delegate { /* Code here */ };
```

or

```
loginForm.Authenticated += (sender, args) => { /* Code here */ };
```